# Double Integral requiring polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I've tried my best in solving the following double integral. I just wanted to be sure I've done the right thing here (b is the vertical axis whilst a is the horizontal axis).

$\int\int(ab^2)\sqrt(a^2+b^2)dadb$ for $1\leq a^2+b^2\leq9, b \geq 0$

I ended up solving for the following:

$2*\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{1}^{3}r^5Cos\theta Sin^2\theta drd\theta$

Am I thinking along the right lines here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral is correct.  Because of the $ab^2$ factor I'm not sure how much you have gained by going to polar coordinates.  But if you now substitute $u = \sin^2 \theta$ the angle integral becomes easy, so I guess the approach is useful.

Comment: many thanks. I'll also try to integrate it without the polar transformation.